# purpose of chdir with a single dot (cd .)

Tags: bash, cd

This might appear a noob question.

While working in bash, if we run `cd .`, it stays in the current folder.
I understand the functionality, however, I am not able to understand the rationale of this functionality?

What would be some practical ways to use this?

Comment: there are many practical uses actually, let's say your current working directory is $HOME, and you have a file you would like to execute inside this directory, you could simply do ./exe_file instead of $HOME/file

Comment: Stack Overflow questions are expected to be about *a specific problem that you actually face*, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. If your code isn't misbehaving on account of this, it's a point of curiosity, and off-topic here.

Comment: @mumcuhkm34, but the OP is talking about `cd .`, not `./exe_file`.

Comment: ...now, there _are_ actually practical use cases -- I've had network filesystems where you had to worry about how fresh your handles are, or could test whether one was still valid by attempting a `cd .` -- but they're rare, unusual, and any "please list all possible uses of X" request is off-topic here anyhow, for much the same reason polls are; such questions are open-ended, and we expect questions to permit canonical answers.

Comment: This is a bit like saying "If you add 0 to a number, it stays the current number. I understand this, but what's the rationale behind this functionality?"

Comment: ... or: Why can I flush the toilet twice?

Comment: My Apologies everyone - my intent was 'not' to generate noise. 

I am a member of the academy. I am designing a training course on one of the flavours of Linux. As an academician, I have to explain the 'why' of a concept as well.

Comment: Some "why"s boil down to "because someone would need to do work to prevent it from being allowed, and there's no reason to do that work". The example hek2mgl used is particularly on point there. Sometimes you _do_ need to flush a toilet twice, but nobody designed if to have that capability as an intentional feature; it just falls out from the mechanics of how the easy/obvious design works.

Answer (score 5):

The primary use case I've seen for `cd .` is to test whether your file handle on the current directory is still valid.

If you're on a directory from a network share -- NFS, or the like -- it can be possible for directories to be remotely deleted, but for the local client to still believe they're accessible and in use.

`cd .` is a way to trigger an error if your handle on the current working directory is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

That command has no functionality. But in a POSIX-compliant environment, if you add a `-P` option, then it has functionality: it resolves symlinks. So for example on a Mac, if you `cd` to a path with a symlink:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/Current
```

...then do `cd -P .` ... you will point to:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C
```

Comment: Except `cd` doesn't read stdin, so it's more like `cd $(pwd)`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, better to use and encourage `cd "$PWD"`; both more correct (on account of the quoting) and vastly more efficient (as it doesn't need to fork a subprocess to run the `pwd` command).

Answer (score 2):

This is the only "practical" case that came to my mind

```
$ cd .
cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

when your process has a current working directory referencing a directory that has been removed by another process.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is a special file that represents the current directory.

There are plenty of things which make use of directories and it is sometimes useful to refer to the current directory.

Changing the directory *to* the current directory is not one of those.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example where `cd .` fails:

```
mkdir my_error
cd my_error
rm -rf ../my_error
cd .
```

When the `rm` is embedded in a difficult script or can be done by some other cleanup process, is can be an useful check.

Answer (score 0):

I use a build script which removes and recreates a directory.

The old directory disappears and new appears with new inode.

If, in one of my shells my $PWD is that reappeared directory and I notice
it became unusable (and I know it was recreated), I just

`$ cd .`

to get the (new) directory useable again and can continue my work there.

Comment: `.` isn't guaranteed to refer to the new inode. You'd want `cd "$PWD"` to have a firm guarantee of the desired functionality.

Comment: perhaps so -- I used to do `cd $PWD` (not `cd "$PWD"` though ;D). just that `cd .` in interactive (zsh?!) shell has been working for me so I've been using it. should it fail I'd probably try $PWD.

Comment: zsh is a special case -- because it chooses not to comply with POSIX in places where the standard is stupid, there (and only there -- not in bash or sh or ksh scripts) is it safe to leave out the quotes. (I prefer compliance with even dumb standards, which is why I stick with bash; back when I tried zsh, I found myself writing buggy code whenever I wrote a script for any other shell on account of getting used to its selective compliance choices).

Comment: that's true that zsh is sometimes standard-incompliant, but I did not leave quotes away because of zsh, but because my $PWD should never have $IFS characters there (and if I used some other shell I'd probably noticed -- if I did not use '.' ;D). I've used zsh since 1995, and I recall writing buggy code past. these days I always test things with `dash -c '...'` from (zsh) command line. in my scripts my "template" always includes `emulate ksh` if zsh is detected, and then  `set -euf` ...

Comment: Assuming that what _should_ be true _actually is_ true is a good way to get in trouble. If you haven't seen the story I keep retelling about a major data loss incident... a former employer once wrote the scripts for pruning old backups assuming that directory names would contain nothing but hex digits. They wrote all the code that could write to that directory themselves, so this seemed a reasonable assumption on its face. One day, they add a new program writing data to be backed up, written in Python; a C library it uses has a buffer overflow, which dumps random data into RAM, [...]

Comment: ...which corrupts the string with the filename, putting a whitespace-surrounded `*` in it; loss of data used to support customer billing commences -- a very expensive mess to clean up. Moral of this story: assuming that what you _think_ will be true is always _actually_ true can get one in some sticky and expensive situations.

Comment: (That said, I don't at all advise `set -e`; it's [very prone to surprising behavior](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105); better to know you don't have it, and rely on explicit error handling with thorough code reviews & a requirement that scripts be shellcheck-clean. If reading the above link and in a hurry, skip the story for the exercises below; they're the most important part).

Comment: right, it was surprise that after `test -d nosuchdir && echo no dir` execution continued...